# Customising a standard B2C User Flow without updating client

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

We are currently using the `B2C_1_SignInNative` User Flow in an Android and iOS app. That user flow has a User Name and Password UI as well as a "Don't have an account? Sign up now" optional flow.

We are using the out of the box customisation capability to show a custom wrapping page into which the standard UI is injected. This has served us well while the app has only been available as private release however we will soon be moving to public app store so will be inviting users outside of the app and the app B2C flow will be sign in only.

We'd like to remove the "Sign up now" flow from **existing installs**. Is it possible to remove that? Alternatively are we allowed to add some custom CSS to our wrapping page to hide the link?

**UPDATE**

So we definitely can add some custom CSS to hide the "Sign up now" action but unfortunately the page and contents are cached in the app browser. We are relying on the Microsoft.Identity.Client library to show the browser UI

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using a "Sign up and sign in" flow.

In order to not have the "Sign up now" option, you can create a "Sign In" only flow by selecting one of the bellow during flow creation:

[image: Creating new flow]

Comment: The "Sign In" only flow is a perfect solution for ongoing installs however that does not  fix the UI for users who have the app and are not upgrading